# Setting a group of wxPython sliders from a sqlite database

Tags: wxpython

I have 14 wx.Sliders, self.slide0 through self.slide15, and a sqlite3 database that holds values for the sliders as a set.

The user decides which set he would like to access from a text entry dialog and the program gets the values for that row.

```
def onSliders(self, event):     
    dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, "Enter the Set Number for this profile", " Settings","")
    if dlg.ShowModal()==wx.ID_OK:
        self.sliderSet = dlg.GetValue()
        val = self.c.execute('SELECT * from Sliders WHERE Index_Row =?', (self.sliderSet)).fetchall()
        val = val[0][2:]
        for i in self.allSlides:
            i.SetValue(val) # This is where it goes off the rails
```

val = [(1, 1, 57, 58, 54, 25, 89, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)]

The first two values are not slide settings so

```
val = val[0][2:]
val = (57, 58, 54, 25, 89, 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I have a list of allSlides. How do I iterate through all of the slides and the values and set each slide to the corresponding value?

Is the only way to do this is by setting each individually?

```
slide0.SetValue(val[0])
slide1.SetValue(val[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple counter to access the values:

```
import wx

class Panel1(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        #self.log = log
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
        self.slider0 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 0, 0, 10,style=wx.SL_LABELS,size=wx.Size(300, -1))
        self.slider1 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 0, 0, 10,style=wx.SL_LABELS,size=wx.Size(300, -1))
        self.slider2 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 0, 0, 10,style=wx.SL_LABELS,size=wx.Size(300, -1))
        self.slider3 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 0, 0, 10,style=wx.SL_LABELS,size=wx.Size(300, -1))
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5,5)
        sizer.Add(self.slider0, (1,2))
        sizer.Add(self.slider1, (2,2))
        sizer.Add(self.slider2, (3,2))
        sizer.Add(self.slider3, (4,2))
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.s = [self.slider0,self.slider1,self.slider2,self.slider3]
        x = [5,6,7,8]
        counter = 0
# Simple method using a list of sliders
#        for i in self.s:
#            i.SetValue(x[counter])
#            counter +=1

#Avoid using a list, quiz the contents of the panel for all slider elements
        children = self.GetChildren()
        for child in children:
            if child.GetClassName() == "wxSlider":
                child.SetValue(x[counter])
                counter += 1


app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "slider test", size = (600, 350))
Panel1(frame, -1)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]